# $n^3+7$ cannot be a square number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. What I have to show is that $n^3+7 \neq k^2$ for any integer $k$.

I assumed that $n^3+7=k^2$ for some integer $k$.

What I did :

$$(n+2)(n^2-2n+4)=k^2+1$$
$$k^2=-1 \mod{n+2}$$
$$(\frac{k}{n+2})=1$$

Another approach.

$$n^3+7=k^2 \mod{4} $$
Then $n$ should be a form of $4u+1$ and $k$ should be a form of $4l$ or $4l+2$.

But I failed to proceed this approach because it is too complicate.

Comment: Your second approach will not work, since $1^3+7 \equiv 2^3 \pmod4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather a classic problem regarding a specific type of Diophantine Equation called 'Mordell's equation', which is $y^2=x^3+k (x\in\mathbb{Z})$

Take a look at [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf)  article by Keith Conrad. Theorem 2.1. will solve your problem.

Comment: Perhaps a related equation is the generalized Ramanujan–Nagell equation, e.g., $y^2=2^n +7$, which has at most $3$ solutions. This is more difficult to show.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Don't you mean $2^n-7$? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: No, $y^2=2^n-7$ has $5$ solutions. The OP asked here for $y^2=x^3+7$, not $y^2=x^3-7$.