Can $x^3 + 7$ Ever Be Square?
Can $x^3 + 7$ ever be a square integer, for integer $x$ ? If not, how can this be proved ?
I have tested with a quick Python script and have reached $x = $ approx. 14 billion, with no squares yet found.
import gmpy2

x = 1
output_gap = 10**7

while True :
    if x % output_gap == 0 :
        print('x = %s' % f"{x:,}")
    y = x**3 + 7
    if (gmpy2.is_square(y)) :
        print('Square detected at x = %s' % f"{x:,}")
    x += 1


See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514571/42969, and this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332360/42969

$y^2=x^3+7$ Is an Elliptic Curve over Q & It has a Rank Zero so it has only Finitely Many Rational points on a Curve.
